# MvxRadioGroupSelectedIndexBinding

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

i created a RadioGroupSelectedIndexBinding from the source of MvxRadioGroupSelectedItemBinding.

It works ok, but not at viewmodel startup: the binding from viewmodel to view is called but at this time the RadioGroup has no child views. It seems they haven't been inflated yet.

This is a "bug" (or feature :p) in Mvvmcross custom inflater/binding ? Or is there something to overload in MvxAndroidTargetBinding ?

Edit: code of MvxRadioGroupSelectedIndexBinding (Index, not Item: different from MvxRadioGroupSelectedItemBinding).

```
public class MvxRadioGroupSelectedIndexBinding : MvxAndroidTargetBinding
{
    bool stopListeningCheckChanged = false;

    private int selectedIndex = -2;
    public int SelectedIndex
    { 
        get { return selectedIndex; }
        set { if(value != selectedIndex) { selectedIndex = value; FireValueChanged(SelectedIndex); } }
    }

    public static void Register(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.RegisterCustomBindingFactory<RadioGroup>("SelectedIndex", radioGroup => new MvxRadioGroupSelectedIndexBinding(radioGroup));
    }

    public MvxRadioGroupSelectedIndexBinding(RadioGroup radioGroup) : base(radioGroup)
    {
        if (radioGroup == null)
        {
            Mvx.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "RadioGroup SelectedIndex: radioGroup is null");
            return;
        }

        radioGroup.CheckedChange += CheckedChange;
        radioGroup.ChildViewAdded += RadioGroupOnChildViewAdded;
    }

    private void RadioGroupOnChildViewAdded(object sender, ViewGroup.ChildViewAddedEventArgs childViewAddedEventArgs)
    {
        var radioGroup = Target as RadioGroup;
        if (selectedIndex == radioGroup.ChildCount-1)
        {
            stopListeningCheckChanged = true;
            radioGroup.Check(radioGroup.GetChildAt(selectedIndex).Id);
            stopListeningCheckChanged = false;
        }
    }

    private void CheckedChange(object sender, RadioGroup.CheckedChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (stopListeningCheckChanged)
            return;

        var radioGroup = Target as RadioGroup;
        var checkedId = e.CheckedId;

        if (checkedId == View.NoId)
        {
            SelectedIndex = -1;
            return;
        }

        for (var i = radioGroup.ChildCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (checkedId == radioGroup.GetChildAt(i).Id)
            {
                SelectedIndex = i;
                return;
            }
        }
        SelectedIndex = -1;
        Mvx.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "RadioGroup id not found: {0}", checkedId);
    }

    public override void SetValue(object index)
    {
        var radioGroup = Target as RadioGroup;
        if (radioGroup == null)
            return;

        stopListeningCheckChanged = true;
        selectedIndex = (int)index;
        if (selectedIndex < 0 || selectedIndex >= radioGroup.ChildCount)
        {
            radioGroup.ClearCheck();
        }
        else
        {
            radioGroup.Check(radioGroup.GetChildAt(selectedIndex).Id);
        }
        stopListeningCheckChanged = false;
    }

    public override Type TargetType
    {
        get { return typeof(object); }
    }

    protected override void SetValueImpl(object target, object value)
    {
    }

    public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
    {
        get { return MvxBindingMode.TwoWay; }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
    {
        if (isDisposing)
        {
            var radioGroup = Target as RadioGroup;
            if (radioGroup != null)
            {
                radioGroup.CheckedChange -= CheckedChange;
                radioGroup.ChildViewAdded -= RadioGroupOnChildViewAdded;
            }
        }
        base.Dispose(isDisposing);
    }
}
```

And usage

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        local:MvxBind="SelectedIndex SelectedChoiceIndex">
        <RadioButton
            android:text="choice 1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RadioButton
            android:text="choice 2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

The "bug" is that when SetValue is called, the RadioGroup has no childs. I suppose the custom inflater create and binds views at the same time. In fact it should bind views only when their childs are inflated. I may be wrong though, i've not checked the source code. And it could have other bad side effects.

Comment: I found a workaround by handling the ChildViewAdded event. But this is silly.

Comment: Code would help in this question. The sample in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Droid/Resources/Layout/Test_RadioGroup.axml seems to work ok for me.

Comment: Yes using binding works. But i don't use this one, i use mine. Code posted in 5 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

> This is a "bug" (or feature :p) in Mvvmcross custom inflater/binding ?

Neither - I think this is simply out of scope of what the `MvxRadioGroup` was designed to target.

`MvxRadioGroupSelectedItemBinding` was a user contribution and I believe it was designed to be used exactly as shown in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/pull/8:

```
<MvxRadioGroup
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:textSize="40dp"
  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/item_radio"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items;SelectedItem SelectedItem"
 />
```

=> so it is designed to work for lists of items where the `ItemsSource` is first set, and then the `SelectedItem` is also set.

I don't believe the author of that MvxRadioGroup had any intention of supporting AXML based lists of radio choices.

---

With that said, if anyone wants to author a more extensive RadioGroup solution - e.g. one that can cope with AXML defined lists or that can cope with `ItemsSource` changes after `SelectedItem` has been set, then I think this should be perfectly possible to do - and it looks like you've already gone a long way towards this :) To "perfectly" handle all combinations of dynamic and static list changes, would probably require using some kind of technique which rechecks the `SelectedItem` property each and every time the `ItemsSource` and/or static items have been added. For practical reasons I think this recheck would need to be performed within some custom RadioGroup and/or binding based code - I don't think there's any way to do this within the XML inflation handlers as Android simply doesn't present any suitable `childrenInflatedAndAdded` type callbacks during inflation.

It may also be interesting to note that XAML presents similar challenges in this area - e.g. see [Silverlight XAML Attribute Definition Order Matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301119/silverlight-xaml-attribute-definition-order-matters) for a XAML `ComboBox` scenario where the items must be set **before** the selected item.